# Request returning nothing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have this button which should show user details after clicking:

```
<a href="{{url('/show')}}"  data-id="<?php echo $user->id;?>"><button class="btn btn-info">Show Details</button></a>
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/show', 'NewController@show');
```

And the controller

```
public function show(Request $request)
{
    $user=User::with('reports')->where('id',$request->id)->first();
    return view('index')->with('user',$user);          
}
```

The problem is `$request->id` returns nothing? why can't this be done? What is the solution?

Comment: You should learn html first

Comment: @Chay22 ok. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass user id as a query string data-* is a misc data which is handled with jQuery. If you want user id in controller then pass data in query string

You can do it like this:

```
<a href="{{url('/show?id='.$user->id)}}"><button class="btn btn-info">Show Details</button></a>
```